# How to connect to a server connected on a modem through a router?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, modem

I have, I believe, a very simple setup that schematically looks like that:

```
          ┌─────┐
    ┌─────┤ NAS │
    │     └─────┘
    │   192.168.1.2
┌───┴───┐
│ Modem │
└───┬───┘
    │     ┌──────┐     ┌───────┐
    └─────┤Router│─────┤Clients│ 
          └──────┘     └───────┘
        192.168.1.3   192.168.50.x
```

I have a Modem that I can access and manage on `192.168.1.1`. I've disabled DCHP on it and assigned 2 static addresses (using mac addresses):

- `192.168.1.2` for the NAS
- `192.168.1.3` for the Router

On the Router (an ASUS one) that I can access and manage on `192.168.50.1`. DHCP is enabled. I set up manually the WAN IP to `192.168.1.3`. So far so good. All router's clients can connect to internet.

I don't understand why I can't connect to the NAS (can't even ping it) (`192.168.1.2`) but I can to the modem admin panel (`192.168.1.1`) when I'm connected to the router (having a `192.168.50.x` IP).

I looked for a way to switch my ISP's modem into bridge mode which seems the way to go (am I wrong?) but I didn't find any options in there. Therefore I tried to set a routing rule inside the ISP's modem which look like this:

```
Destination: 192.168.50.1
Subnet:      255.255.255.0
Gateway:     192.162.1.2 # NAS ip
```

Should I setup something inside the router? Does anybody have an idea of what should I do to be able to connect to IPs connected to the Modem? And even better, what should I do to be able to connect to it using hostnames (e.g. mysupernas.local)?

Answer (score 0):

Connect your NAS to your router, not the modem, so that all your gear is one subnet.

That will work and will work better than what you have

This will also work better than static IP addressing and in any event, your router is the DHCP server.

You can move the router very near to the modem to facilitate this, or possibly use the modem as modem / router and do it that way.

Comment: I know. Indeed, this fixes my issue. I already tried (just to make sure my NAS was actually working...). But I can't keep a cable connected to the NAS and the router because there are in different locations and passing a cable isn't an option.

Comment: Move your NAS closer to your router.  You said my answer fixes your issue. You can also use POE connection via your wiring to connect.

Comment: Moving devices closer or using PoE are not the question. I would not have asked this question here if I would not require specifically this setup.

Comment: Putting devices on different subnets always causes issues. Many such issues in this forum trying to separate devices by subnets.

Answer (score 0):

Set the netmask of the router and modem to `255.255.0.0`,
and every other device that finds itself disconnected.

This will convert your local network to become `192.168.x.x`,
so it will be one subnet that includes both `192.168.1.x` and
`192.168.50.x`.

Comment: Modem has DHCP disabled so DHCP services will need to change